# How to use max function in python? I'm getting TypeError

Tags: python, max

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Max function gives `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

```
>>> max(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> max(1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>>
```

Comment: My bet is that you have defined a variable called `max` before.

Comment: check this `1()` you will get the same error. Because max is shadowed by a int variable you created as bereal stated.

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear: you have redefined max to be an int in your code. Or you use someone else's code that does that.
So you probably have something like this somewhere

```
max = 4
```

This is why it is seen as very bad practice to use built-in names as variable names. Python allows you to do it, but it's error prone.

Prefer the use of `maximum` or `max_` if you really want something close to `max`.

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
In [1]: a = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [2]: max(a)
Out[2]: 5
```

If you have not shadowed [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) somewhere, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have somewhere in your code defined a variable named `max`

```
max = something
```

Because:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
print max(a)
```

Outputs `5` and works perfectly.

Comment: Exactly. Works fine. I had another variable named max.  My bad. This is embarrasing